# Need to know PHP CS Fixer rule

Tags: php, php-cs-fixer

I'm using PHP CS Fixer for my code. But I am also using PHP as template engine and want one liner PHP code.

When I write this:

```
<!-- some html code -->
<?php foreach ($modules as $module) { ?>
<!-- some html code ->
```

...then I get this after the PHP CS Fixer is done:

```
<!-- some html code -->
<?php foreach ($modules as $module) {

?>
<!-- some html code -->
```

Which PHP CS rule is affected and can I disable to prevent this code formatting behaviour?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Found the solution by myself. It was the **braces [@PSR2, @Symfony]** rule.

The --verbose option and the --dry-run flag helped me a lot. Read the [PHP CS Fixer manual](https://github.com/FriendsOfPHP/PHP-CS-Fixer#usage) for more information.